# Manifolds whose boundaries are real / complex projective spaces

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology, projective-space

1. What are some simple manifolds $M$ whose boundaries are $\mathbb{RP}^2$ or $\mathbb{RP}^n$ in general?

Namely $\partial M= \mathbb{RP}^n.$

2. What are some simple manifolds $N$ whose boundaries are $\mathbb{CP}^2$ or $\mathbb{CP}^n$ in general?

Namely $\partial N= \mathbb{CP}^n.$

Some trial attempt: I know that we can have
$\partial D^2= \mathbb{RP}^1.$ and
$\partial D^3= \mathbb{CP}^1.$ I dont know whether there are simple topology that also do the job for the above two questions?

Comment: I would write $I$ to mean the unit interval, and $\partial I^1 = S^0$. It is true that $\Bbb{RP}^1 \cong S^1$ and so bounds a disc.

Answer (score 6):

This should really be a comment on Mike's excellent answer, but it won't fit.  As Mike twice uses the fact that "$\chi(M)$ odd implies $M$ is not a boundary", I figure I would add a proof of the fact.

Let $N$ be a manifold with $\partial N = M$.  The goal is to show that $\chi(M)$ is even.  If $N$ is even dimensional, $M$ is an odd dimensional closed manifold, so $\chi(M) = 0$, which is even.  Thus, we may assume that $N$  is odd dimensional.

Now, consider the manifold $N'$ obtained by gluing to copies of $N$ together along the commmon boundary.  Then $\chi(N') = 0$ since $N'$ is an odd dimensional closed manifold.  But we also see that $\chi(N') = \chi(N) + \chi(N) - \chi(M)$, so $ \chi(M) = 2\chi(N)$ is even.

Comment: thanks +1, that is good to have more responses

Answer (score 5):

$\Bbb{RP}^{2n}$ do not bound any manifolds (odd Euler characteristic $1$).

There is a circle bundle $\Bbb{RP}^{2n+1} \to \Bbb{CP}^n$ given by sending every real line in $\Bbb C^{n+1}$ to the complex line it is contained in. (There is a circle's worth of real lines in a given complex line.) Filling this circle bundle in with a disc bundle gives an oriented manifold that $\Bbb{RP}^{2n+1}$ bounds; an element of this manifold is a complex line $\ell \subset \Bbb C^{n+1}$ equipped with an equivalence class of vector $v \in \ell$ with $\|v\| \leq 1$, setting $v \sim v'$ if $v' = \pm v$.

$\Bbb{CP}^{2n}$ do not bound any manifolds (odd Euler characteristic $2n+1$).

There is a 2-sphere bundle $\Bbb{CP}^{2n+1} \to \Bbb{HP}^n$ given by sending every complex line in $\Bbb H^{n+1}$ to the quaternionic line it is contained in. There is a 2-sphere's worth of complex lines in each quaternionic line (because of the isomorphism $S^3/S^1 = \Bbb{CP}^1 \cong S^2$). We may fill this in fiberwise with a 3-ball to obtain an oriented manifold $\Bbb{CP}^{2n+1}$ bounds; an element of this is a quaternionic line in $\Bbb H^{2n+1}$ and an equivalence class of $v \in \ell$, where we say $v \sim v'$ if there is a unit complex number $\lambda$ with $\lambda v = v$.

Comment: Would you happen to know what manifold has $\mathbb{H}P^{2n+1}$ as a boundary?  I asked this on MO years ago and still don't have an answer  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14698/what-manifold-has-mathbbhpodd-as-a-boundary.  The only progress:   These mystery manifolds must be non-orientable, unless $n = 0$ when $\mathbb{H}P^1\cong S^4$ bounds $D^5$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito That's a very interesting question and I do not have an answer in 5 minutes thought. Unfortunately, I think that's all the time I can spare right now, but I think this gets added to my list of questions to fiddle with when I am bored ;)